# Requesting explanation about Certification Failure (Partner Request ID 2004100040003081)

Tags: add-on, office-store, appsource

**REQUEST TO MICROSOFT CERTIFICATION TEAM - REF. PARTNER REQUEST TICKET ID 2004100040003081**

Please explain why our submission received the failure notice 1100.1.4 shown below.
What should we change in our submission to clear this hurdle?

**PLEASE NOTE:**
Our offer is FREE and requires no purchase of a license or additional services.
Our service integrates with Outlook in M365. No additional services are required. We should not fail “1100.1.4 Additional Service or Account Disclosures”. If certification disagrees, please comment in the certification report so we understand how you arrive at this conclusion so that we can address the issue.

**Failure Notice:**
General Content
1100.1.4 Additional Service or Account Disclosures
Your offer contains features which are unlocked through the purchase of a license or additional services. If your product offers in-app purchases, you must select the "My product requires purchase of a service or offers additional in-app purchases" check box on the Product Setup tab when submitting your offer via Partner Center. Please update your offer as required and resubmit.

Thank you!
Dan

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Answer (score -1):

If a user has to pay to use the add-in at any point such as a free trial ending or to unlock additional functionality, that checkbox must be marked and that fact clearly disclaimed in the description of the offer. If this is not the case and the add-in is 100% free for users, you can mention that in the certification notes of the submission.

Comment: "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."